# Remove comment block <!-- --> from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

How can I remove comment blocks in a string. This is a part of my string that I want to remove.

```
<!--
[if !mso]> <style> v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} o\:*    {behavior:url(#default#VML);} w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);} </style> <![endif]

-->
```

Comment: You'd better add what you have done.

Comment: I wanted to find a regex to remove the content between this block of comment. but I didn't find anything till now, and it works fine.

myString = Regex.Replace(myString , @"(?s)(?<=<!--).+?(?=-->)", "").Trim();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a regex to remove this kind of comment block

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString , @"(?s)(?<=<!--).+?(?=-->)", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

in these cases I'd advice you to use an external lib such as "Html Agility Pack"
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/
It's availble via NuGet & on their codeplex page you'll find code examples on houw to use the library.

It will enable you to load the html model in C#. By that you can pull out the things you don't need, or manipulate certain tags etc.. etc.. Or even, such as in your case, extract the comments inside an html-doc. I don't have the exact code snippet for your case, but you'll be able to work it out very fast with this library.

Doing this yourself, even with REGEX, will cost a lot of time implementing and will be error prone at first. Look at it like this: don't reinvent the wheel ;).

Comment: Thank you. It's a good library. but I think this is too much for my issue. I found an easier way and I posted as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I understand that for limited strings it is ok to do it via regex.. I assumed you had a whole bunch of scenario's, and the one you pointed out was just a sample of what was a whole bunch. In that case regex is ok I guess indeed.